problem with display size after disconnecting external display and changing user account
Here is the problem I am facing. I am logged in into 2 accounts, A and B, and have been using both accounts with an external display. Then, while on account A, I unplug the display and switch to account B. I then get the display like on the attached photo.  The toolbar is not there, and the desktop is not taking up the whole screen, and many other things are off.
I tried changing things in the display preferences, but nothing works.
Also tried
killall -KILL Dock

in the terminal, but also no change.
I am wondering what might be causing this and what is the easiest workaround.
I found these 2 workarounds:

Switch back to A, then switch again to B, and then things looks ok.
connect any external display and disconnect it.


